# Making buttons with select list inline

Tags: html, css

I've got some CSS here. I can't find a way to make select list and two buttons in one line, that it would look like:

```
>[seleclist]<
```

Here is my css of both buttons > and <:

```
.impBut2 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

And select list:

```
.edit_asSelPerc {
    padding: 2px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;

}
```

And here is my html code:

```
                            <div class="percent_butt">
                                <input type="button" class="impBut2" value="&gt;" onclick="javascript:addUser(document.resourceFrm)" />
                                <select name="percentage_assignment" class="edit_asSelPerc">';
                                    for ($i = 5; $i <= 100; $i+=5) {
                                        echo ('<option ' . (($i==100) ? 'selected="true"' : '') 
                                              . ' value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '%</option>');
                                    }
            echo                '</select>  
                                <input type="button" class="impBut2" value="&lt;" onclick="javascript:removeUser(document.resourceFrm)" />
                            </div>
```

Help please!

Comment: use `display:inline`

Comment: @Amitsingh But i want to keep them in center of div... And when i make them inline they float left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this..

**HTML:**

```
<div class="percent_butt">
          <input type="button" class="impBut2" value="&gt;" onclick="javascript:addUser(document.resourceFrm)" />
          <select name="percentage_assignment" class="edit_asSelPerc">';
              for ($i = 5; $i <= 100; $i+=5) {
                  echo ('<option ' . (($i==100) ? 'selected="true"' : '') 
                        . ' value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '%</option>');
              }
echo                '</select>  
          <input type="button" class="impBut2" value="&lt;" onclick="javascript:removeUser(document.resourceFrm)" />
      </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.percent_butt {
  text-align:center;
}

.edit_asSelPerc {
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;

}

.impBut2 {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```